# Customised text formatting with php

Tags: php, html, formatting

Using PHP, how would I convert an HTML string say, `'+text+'` to `'<em>text</em>'` so that if a user types +text+ in an input, it outputs as *text*?

Comment: `+text+` is inserted in the input and `<em>text</em>` is stored in a database table

Answer (score 2):

You can use str_replace along side explode or regex

```
$text_string = '+TEST+';
$text = explode("+", $text_string);
$text = $text[1];
$replaced_text = str_replace("+$text+", "<em>$text</em>", $text_string);
echo $replaced_text; // output: <em>TEST</em>
```

Comment: Elegant solution, however, would the above apply to a string with multiple occurrences? eg: `+test+ is a +wonderful+ thing`

Answer (score 0):

if all you want to do is use  you can do.

```
$input = "+text+";

$input = trim($input, '+');

$input = '<em>' . $input . '</em>';
```

Comment: This may be inefficient as this would ONLY work if + and + are the first and last letters in a string, I'm pretty sure his string wouldn't be this way if the users are inputting it.

Comment: hard to say what is exactly happening with the questions description but yes you are correct. However if somehow they can ensure that + is always at the start and end this would be much faster.